# How does folding over comma work?

Tags: c++, c++17

How does the following line unfold?

```
template <class... Ts>
void print_all(std::ostream& os, Ts const&... args) {
    (void(os << args), ...);
}
```

Applying the rule,

> Unary right fold (E op ...) becomes E<sub>1</sub> op (... op (E<sub>N-1</sub> op E<sub>N</sub>))

provided by [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold),

```
E  = void(os << args)
op = ,
```

Then the expansion becomes

```
void(os << args[0], ..., (args[N-3], (args[N-2], args[N-1])) )
```

?

How about

```
v.push_back(args), ...
```

Does it become

```
v.push_back(args[0], (args[1], ..., (args[N-2], args[N-1])))
```

Both the expansion and the parenthesis are confusing.  Would someone explain?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to unpack the *entire* expression that contains the parameter pack. Not just the parameter pack. Just following the rules:

> Unary right fold (E op ...) becomes E<sub>1</sub> op (... op (E<sub>N-1</sub> op E<sub>N</sub>))

You're right that `op` is `,` and `E` is `void(os << args)`, where `args` is the pack, but E<sub>i</sub> isn't just args<sub>i</sub>, it's the *whole expression* `void(os << args#i)`. So:

```
(void(os << args), ...);
```

becomes (using `[]` for convenience):

```
void(os << args[0]), void(os << args[1]), void(os << args[2]), ..., void(os << args[N-1]);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
os << args[0];
os << args[1];
...
os << args[N-1];
```

Similarly, `(v.push_back(args), ...)` (the parentheses are required) would expand as:

```
v.push_back(args[0]), v.push_back(args[1]), ..., v.push_back(args[N-1]);
```

---

Note that you could also write this example as a binary left fold:

```
(os << ... << args);
```

which would expand as:

```
((((os << args[0]) << args[1]) ... ) << args[N-1]);
```

Comment: To be more precise, should the unpacking of the unary case be identical to the binary case with all the parenthesis? (assuming the same unpacking order is applied).

Comment: @CandyChiu No, they're not the same. `(std::cout << x) << y` does not necessarily do the same thing as `std::cout << x; std::cout << y;`. `std::cout << x` might, for instance, return `std::cerr`.

Comment: @CandyChiu Assuming everything followed all the relevant conventions, then yes, it would do the same thing. But you can’t always assume that. 
`std::cout << x` might return `cerr`, or it might return something with an overloaded `operator,`. And in both cases order is guaranteed, *even with overloaded operators*. The built-in `operator,` was always a sequencing point (or had similar semantics, once the term “sequencing point” was removed), and C++17 says that overloaded operators sequence the same way as their built-in counterparts.

Comment: @Barry did you omit some parenthesis in the unary expansion?  void(os << args[0]), (void(os << args[1]), (void(os << args[2]), ... (void(os << args[N-2], void(os << args[N-1]))...));   the parenthesis may be important in other scenarios.

Comment: @CandyChiu Yes, but they're not important in this scenario, so they don't really help in explaining what happens. They're just... more parentheses.

Comment: why is casting to void needed?

Comment: Why does the comma folding need outer parentheses?

Comment: @Silicomancer All folding requires parentheses, it's part of the grammar.