# How to use a fold expression to call a chain of member functions

Tags: c++, c++20, fold-expression

I have a builder class like this

```
class Builder
{
public:
   Builder (SomeData someData);
   
   template <class FooType, class... FooConstructorArgs>
   Builder&& addFoo (FooConstructorArgs&&... args) &&
   {
      addInternal (new FooType (std::forward<FooConstructorArgs> (args)...);
      return std::move (*this);
   }
//...
}
```

Now there is a function like this

```
std::string createUuid();

template <std::constructible_from<std::string> FooType>
void bar (SomeData data)
{
   auto builder = Builder (data).addFoo<FooType> (createUuid());
   
   // do something fancy with that builder
}
```

However, what I really want is a function signature like this:

```
template <std::constructible_from<std::string>... FooTypes>
void bar (SomeData data)
```

Where `addFoo` is called chained for each type, e.g.

```
addFoo<Bar, Baz> (data);

// expands internally to
auto builder = Builder (data).addFoo<Bar> (createUuid()).addFoo<Baz> (createUuid());
```

I'm generally aware of the existence of fold expressions, but I can't figure out the syntax to write this as a fold expression. I'm not even sure if chained member function calls are supported with fold expressions at all. Can someone either give me a hint on how to implement it or confirm that this is indeed impossible?

Comment: Use a fold expression with `,` as the operator (to generate `x.addFoo<Bar>(createUuid()), x.addFoo<Baz>(createUuid()), ...`) (since it doesn't work with `.`).

Comment: Did you notice the signature of `Builder&& addFoo (FooConstructorArgs&&... args) &&`? It's only callable on an rvalue, so I think that solution won't work here?

Comment: Then `std::move(x).` instead of `x.`, no big deal. Or rewrite your `addFoo` to also accept lvalues (using explicit `this` parameter helps here, if your compiler supports it (currently only MSVC does)).

Comment: Related: [How does folding over comma work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603533/how-does-folding-over-comma-work)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the comma operator(`,`) to expand the parameter pack

```
template <std::constructible_from<std::string>... FooTypes>
void bar (SomeData data)
{
  auto builder = Builder (data);
  ((builder = std::move(builder).addFoo<FooTypes>(createUuid())), ...);
}
```